# Get value of an Object type by key in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an `object` type variable

```
let ref_schema_data: object
```

The value of `ref_schema_data`

```
{ '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema',
  '$id': 'tc_io_schema_top.json',
  allOf:
   [ { type: 'object', required: [Array], properties: [Object] } ] }
```

This is how I am assigning value to `ref_schema_data`

```
function load_schema(filename: string, filepath: string):object {
    let json_data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(filepath, filename),'utf8')
    return JSON.parse(json_data)
}
```

I am finding it difficult to get any value out of the object by key. For e.g. I need to get `ref_schema_data["$id"]` . But that's not working .

What is the mistake I am doing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `object` type is very rarely useful. It doesn't define any properties of the object, so no property access is allowed. Instead, define a type that matches your object's shape. For instance:

```typescript
interface Thingy {
    type: string;
    required: something[];   // I don't know from the question what you have in this array
    properties: something[]; // Or this one
}
interface SchemaData {
    $schema: "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema", // A string literal type
    $id: string;
    allOf: Thingy[]; // An array type
}
```

Then if you assign `SchemaData` as the type of `ref_schema_data`, you'll be able access the properties in the object. (Obviously, you'll have to fill in the `something` placeholders above.)

More in [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types).

---

In a comment you've said:

> the only thing is my schema properties are not constant , it will vary. So i thought difficult to have interface for same. My requirement is basically read JSON object and get value for some keys if exists

In that case, your interface uses an [*index signature*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) (allow any property name), perhaps allowing the values to be anything (`any`):

```
interface SchemaData {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

That says "a `SchemaData` is an object with any string as a property name, where all the properties have any type." It doesn't provide virtually any type-safety, because when dealing with data that you don't know the shape of, you can't. :-)

[Live example on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQLZwCJxhzIDeAUMpcgNoDWEAngFzIDOYUoA5gLotwgGAbjIBfMmQQB7EO2RQIMAPqtMOOEoAmhOC3RZcBIsgC8pClQBEAElUG4llpYxgwAByYB6TwCtWMgFo7dQA6KSguT00oOBgwAIAGAHZPYNxLABoLShtgTUdkSzAEJWApFTVcJTApNxC-GUzs5DgAG1aAeRgWamaqc37BqjAGNwgnKQAjHwgEMCahoYUARwBXYAVNHs8AKgBBKBiGHc8eLMXBtyha6DBgCFZtnY7p2bATnj6qcX7P0RFJDJ-K0ICFWlIuAAKBTKNIabREELWPIASiEQA)

Or you might just use [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) on `ref_schema_data` instead.

[Live example on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwGYH0LABYILYEMUAmuUuAXDLmAJ4wC8MA3gFAyswBEAJOlnu+ewxQoAB1IB6cQCsI4ALQ8cuAHQg4Ac3EE4uJFDkAGAOzjFfADQs2XAJYF+HKMBQ2QaTEpRQQI5TPDslmwUADYhAPJI5ADaVsGszPFJMFBUIggCIABGUgjAUIFxyayIAI4ArjaIBDHiAFQAgnA6VHXiALpBxWwicD4IcFA2CBC1deE5eVBt7UXBAL5Fs-MA3ExMoJAgIQjKISDqABSIqGb4RCTKnHYAlCtAA)

Comment: I thought of having `interfaces` , the only thing is my `schema properties` are not constant , it will vary. So i thought difficult to have `interface` for same. My requirement is basically `read JSON object` and `get value for some keys if exists` .

Comment: @Crowder  thanks for guiding me on this . I found another simple way of getting `value` for a `key` out of the object -- `_.get(ref_schema_data,"$id")`

Comment: @Dibshare - All that's doing is hiding the problem by making it a completely unnecessary lodash call. Just use `ref_schema_data.$id` with the type `any` or `{[key: string]: any;}` on `ref_schema_data` as shown above.